# prevent animation from moving the character

Tags: unity, animation, movement

As stated in the question I've this problem: I'm using Unity and when playing an animation my character moves from point A to point B without my consent. Here's the code:

```
public class Walk : MonoBehaviour {

    private Animator humanAnimator;
    private iInputProvider input;

    private void Start()
    {
        input = new KeyBoardInput();
        humanAnimator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        walkMe = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        walk();
    }

    private void walk()
    {
        InputWrapper inputWrp = input.GetInputValues();

        animateWalk(inputWrp.verticalMove);
    }

    private void animateWalk(float verticalMove)
    {
        if (-0.1 <= verticalMove && verticalMove <= 0.1) //stand still
        {
            humanAnimator.SetBool("Walk", false);
            Debug.Log(humanAnimator.GetBool("Walk"));
        }
        else if (verticalMove > 0.1) // animate walk forward if the player is walking forward
        {
            humanAnimator.SetBool("Walk", true);
            Debug.Log(humanAnimator.GetBool("Walk"));
        }
        else if (verticalMove < -0.1)
        {
            // walk backward animation needed
        }

    }
}
```

Note that nowhere in the code I change the object position, i just start the animation. Here's the result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYDvT.jpg

note that it's not the effect of the gif, the character actually resets its position after the animation is terminated. I was expecting the character to "run on the place".
Anybody has some idea how can I fix this?

EDIT: if I uncheck the "Apply root motion" check box I've this result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouZxp.jpg . Maybe it could be useful to know that I can't click on "Generate root motion curve" in my animation inspector because it's all uneditable: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lsd9W.jpg

Comment: Probably animation itself has root positioning keys too, try removing them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an option on the Animator Component called `"Apply Root Motion"` this basically asks if you want the animation itself to control character motion(true, checked) or handle it yourself (false, unchecked), In your case you likely want it disabled.

[for extra information on the Animator Component](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Animator.html)

If you end up on this question from google and the above doesn't help and you've also got your animations from Mixamo try re-downloading the animation with "In Place" ticked, if not ticked it applies root motion that unity cannot override.

Comment: Hi thanks but I've already tryied, the result is actually worse: https://imgur.com/4FdeCKH now there's this oscillation ...

Comment: Ok that's strange, how about on your animation clips themselves, does un-checking the different root motion options there make any difference?

Comment: Also did you happen to get the animations from Mixamo?

Comment: Yes! I think you got it! Give me some good news and tell me it's possible ...
I don't have any options about root motion on the clip it self

Comment: If I remember correctly there is an option within Mixamo itself to apply root motion to the models which unity cant override, if you uncheck this and re-download/import the animation that should fix it.

Comment: The option in Mixamo is just called "In Place"

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an in-place checkbox on Mixamo anymore.

Comment: Some animations on Miaxmo are Root motion only and there are also some that are in place only, but I can confirm the option still exists, if I view the animation "Crouched walking" on Mixamo for example, the option is still there.